# Is it possible to post from custom js to .module/custom.php/controller file and get response in custom js while developing custom module in drupal8?

Tags: ajax, drupal

i have this in custom.js file in drupal modules/mymodule/js/ folder

```
  (function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.coorrency = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'modules/mymodule/custom.php',
            type: "POST",
            success:  function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
          });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

and i have to post to modules/mymodule/custom.php

```
<?php

echo "test";

?>
```

and return data from custom.php

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by creating a controller for listening that ajax call

**my_module.routing.yml**

```
my_module.call_back:
      path: '/my_module/call_back'
      defaults:
        _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\DefaultController::callBack'
        _title: 'Call Back'
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Class DefaultController.
 */
class DefaultController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Your Callback
   *
   */
  public function callBack() {
    return ["This is a test" ];
  }
```

**custom.js**

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.coorrency = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/my_module/call_back',
        type: "POST",
        success:  function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You are not hardcoding the URL here instead of using the route name. How can you achieve that?